# counting chars that use delegates (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, string, function, delegates, chars

I have been struggling for a while on how to count characters using delegates on vb.net (console application). If anyone is able to explain how to this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more precise ?  
When you say couting chars, i think of a string and String.Length. 
Obviously, that is not what you are speaking about here.

Counting chars from where ?
Console input ?
More context would help to understand better what you actually means.

Comment: by counting chars, i mean counting the letters that are being used in a text. Like how microsoft word counts every time you type in a word it says in the bottom corner how many you have typed in total. but instead of counting an entire word, only the letters/inputs that make them up. And console application is what i'm using to do this project.

Comment: Counting chars from which inputs ? From a text file ? From a TextBox ? What does this have to do with delegates anyway ?

Comment: here, this is what a project is telling me to do.

Comment: 1) Write a program using various procedures to perform the operations listed below. Call these procedures using delegates. Make sure to document your program and have the program print descriptive text along with the numbers in b. and c.
 a) Print a text string in reverse word order. 
 b) Print the number of characters in the string.
 c) Print number of words in the string.